# Making a getter that accesses another class in JAVA

Tags: java, class, oop, object

Im learning OOP in Java and I am wondering how to create a getter that access data from a seperate class? I have a program that creates people with their names and birth dates. So I have 3 classes, PersonProgram(the main), People, and Date. The People class has the constructor for the Full names which include first name, last name, and birth date. The Date class has the constructor and setters for the date which includes 3 integers for the day, month, and year, and then a method that formats them into a string format. So in my main program, I have an option to print out information about whatever Person is created. So I call the getter of People with

```
Person[selection].getBirthDate;
```

and the getter in my People class is:

```
public Date getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}
```

but I want it to retrieve the formatted date from the toString method in my Date class. Can I just call the toString method from inside the getBirthDate getter?

Comment: As long as you make your method return `String`.

Comment: `public String getBirthDate() { return birthDate.toString(); }`

Comment: In object-oriented terms, using another object to return a value is called delegation. It's perfectly acceptable, if not encouraged.

Comment: By the way, avoiding naming your classes the same as common classes bundled with Java. In this case, `Date` is such a name. Also, that class is now legacy so do not use it; in a real app you could use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for your Birthday field rather than construct your own class.  `LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would be appropriate to use toString() here. In Date class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
}
```

And in People class return a String instead of a Date object. This way you have a clean method interface, as you only want the Date to be read as whole String anyway:

```
public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate.toString();
}
```

Comment: Am I possibly missing an initialization somewhere? I have the code just as yours, but when I run the program the date returns a hex value of some sort , like this: Date@55f96302
and in my main: System.out.println("Birth Date: " + people[selection].getBirthDate());

Comment: You are returning a Date object OR you didn't override the toString() method of the Date class properly. The standard string representation of an Object is the class name + "@" + a memory address. This is what you get there. You have to make the getBirthDate() method return a String (like in my code) AND implement the toString() method i gave you IN the Date class. Of course you'll have to change the variables "day", "month" etc to whatever you named them. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can call from your main method :

```
person[index].getBirthDate().toString();
```

This will return the string you want since the toString method will be invoked on the Date class instance embeeded in the person instance.